# Drupal7 hook_menu for exists node aliases

Tags: drupal-7

I'm developing my module. For module I created special node type and add some nodes with aliases as 'events/my1', 'events/my2'  and 'events/my3'.

In module I use hook_menu function

```
$items['events'] = array(
    'title' => t('Events list'),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'page callback' => '_events_list',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  $items['events/%'] = array(
    'title' => t(''),
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'page callback' => '_event_detail',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
```

On url site.com/events/ opened my page from _events_list() function

On url site.com/events/anyurl/ opened content from _event_detail() function

But when I open site.com/events/my1/ then opened default view for node. Not my code from _event_detail().

How I can fix it? I want for each urls from /events/ show code from my function, not default view.

Answer (score 0):

`hook_menu` defines new URL paths.  For existing URL paths, use [`hook_menu_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_alter/7).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I checked items inside this function and it not have items with keys as page aliases. It just use 'node/%node'. And I can't use it.